# Unable to start Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

There are some stuff I'm trying to do but can't because Task scheduler isn't running and when I try to start Task Scheduler an error message appears.

[image: The Error Message]

Comment: Run from admin elevated command prompt `sfc /scannow`, reboot PC once that completes, and then try again or check that it is back in working order.]